# Can you tell Informix to output trace information to stdout or stderr?

Tags: database, informix

I need to use the Informix 'trace' debugging.

In order to use it, you specify the debug file using `set debug file to .....`

Is it possible to output the trace data to stdout or sterr instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because the server has its standard output and standard error connected to /dev/null (so you wouldn't see anything even if you did redirect to them).  Remember, the database server might not even be on the same continent as you (the ones I use are about 1500 miles from where I sit - when it isn't on my laptop).